# Set post publish date by custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wp-update-post

I created custom fields with ACF to define a new date for my post on wordpress.
I then created this function that updates the date with my custom field and works when I update a post.

```
// Save ACF custom field to date-time post
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    $acfDate = get_field('data_time_post', $post_id);
    //Test if you receive the data field correctly:
    //echo $acfDate;
    //exit (-1);
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
    $my_post['post_date'] = $acfDate;
    wp_update_post ( $my_post );
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

But it doesn't work when I create a new post, only whn update

I think the problem is this function:
wp_update_post

Thank you all.

Comment: I guess you've probably run into an endless loop... so try unhooking and rehooking your function - in that function, try replacing the `wp_update_post()` part with `remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20); wp_update_post ( $my_post ); add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);` ..

Comment: Thanks 1000 for your reply.
Unfortunately it doesn't work ...
But I think I understand what the problem is, I insert the article through the formidable form, so I guess I have to insert something different, otherwise the function does not start ...
Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to ask on the Formidable and/or ACF support forums/site for further assistance.. because those two are 3rd-party plugins, and support for 3rd-party plugins and themes are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.